# How to increase maximum number of rows displayed under desktop icon on Windows desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-8, desktop, icons

Maybe you know that if any Windows desktop icon has too long display name, only first two rows are displayed when it loses the focus. See the second icon in the example:

- focused: 
  [image]
- focus lost: 
  [image]

**What determines how many rows is the limit?

How the number of visible rows can be increased?**

I'm interested especially to change this in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open regedit.exe --> HKEY_CURRENT_USER --> Control Panel --> Desktop --> Windows Metrics. There you can change the values of IconSpacing for horizontal spacing and IconVerticalSpacing for vertical spacing. For example change the value of IconVerticalSpacing to -2750. You have to reboot to see the difference.

[image: Regedit keys to change horizontal and vertical icon spacing]

Windows autocalculates how much text is showed based on these values. If you make this values greater, more text will automatically been shown. As far as I know there's no way make the amount of rows that are shown static.

Comment: Is this the same thing as adjusting the `Window Color and Appearance` properties in `Display Settings`?